# How to convert [abc\tdef\tghi] to ["abc" "def" "ghi"] in Mac Terminal?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have the following variable in Terminal

echo $VAR1

> abc    def    ghi
> <- Separated by tab

How can I convert this to

> "abc" "def" "ghi"
> with single space in-between?

Comment: Since you're on a mac, are you using bash or zsh?

Comment: Do you want a single string with quotes literally included, or do you want three separate strings (as something like an array)? (This basically comes down to: what do you want to do with the result?)

Comment: Yes I am on zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do what you want

```
echo -e "abc\tdef\tghi\tjhg\tmnb" | sed -ne 's/\t/" "/g; s/.*/"\0"/p'
```

Result:

```
"abc" "def" "ghi" "jhg" "mnb"
```

Answer (score 4):

In `zsh`, you can break your string up into an array of quoted words with

```sh
var1=$'abc\tdef\tghi'
words=( "${(qqq)=var1}" )
```

and then turn it back into a single string if wanted with

```sh
var2="${words[*]}"
printf "%s\n" "$var2" # prints "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Or to skip the intermediate array if you don't need it:

```
var2=${(A)${(qqq)=var1}}
```

Comment: See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags for lots of nifty stuff you can with parameter expansion flags.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the variable contains actual tab characters (not backslashes followed by "t"), you can replace tabs with `" "` while expanding the variable (see [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion), a ways down in the list of modifiers), and also add quotes at the beginning and end, like this:

```
"\"${VAR1//$'\t'/\" \"}\""
```

There's a rather complex mix of quoting and escaping modes here. The double-quotes at the very beginning and end make the whole thing a double-quoted string, so the shell doesn't do anything weird to whitespace in it. The various escaped double-quotes in it will all be treated as literal characters (because they're escaped), and just be part of the output. And the pattern string, `$'\t'`, is in ANSI-C quoting mode, so that the `\t` gets converted to an actual tab character.

Here's a couple of examples of using it:

```
% VAR1=$'abc\tdef\tghi'    # Define a variable with actual tab characters
% echo "\"${VAR1//$'\t'/\" \"}\""   # Pass the converted version to a command
"abc" "def" "ghi"
% VAR2="\"${VAR1//$'\t'/\" \"}\""    # Store converted version in another variable
% echo "$VAR2"
"abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage `awk`. For example:

```
user$ $var='abc\tdef\tghi'
user$ $echo -e ${var}
(output)>>> abc def ghi
user$ $echo -e ${var} | awk -F '\t' '{ for (i=1; i <NF; i++) {printf "\"%s\" ", $i}; printf "\"%s\"\n", $NF}' 
(output)>>> "abc" "def" "ghi"
```